# How to force browser to open only on instance of particular action

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, browser

I am doing some ROR stuff and stuck in some weird situation.

I want particular action should open at once at browser window or tab it should not open on multiple tab.

For eg.

If I opened home page of site at one tab then it should not be open at another tab of same browser.

I want this because my page contains heavy data and if I opened it on multiple tab then browser get heavy loaded. So i want avoid this situation by allowing only one instance at time.

I am using 
rails 3.0.1
ruby 1.8.7
jquery 1.4.4
Plz help :)

Comment: you can do it at the client level if they install a [plugin](http://www.troublefixers.com/stop-opening-of-multiple-tabs-of-same-website-or-webpage-in-google-chrome/) and I have seen it done server side but can't remember where, will look around

Comment: this might help http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MultipleTabWindows.aspx

Comment: +1 for raising a question that leads to people learning new things.

Answer (score 4):

DO NOT DO THIS. Ever.

It's the user's right to open as many instances of your site as he wants, and it's your responsibility to deal with that correctly. What you are proposing is essentially abridging the user's right so that you can shirk your responsibility.

Comment: Agreed. However, if you find a case (there's no such thing as "never") that you have to do this eViL thing, at least warn the user before they take that action.

Comment: This is a "never". If you think you have to do this, your design is flawed because you're fighting the browser instead of working with it.

Comment: I'm sorry but every application has a different audience and different requirements. Using "never" in any assertion is dangerous because inflexibility is quite frankly a terrible characteristic in any development environment.

Comment: There are some general principles that shouldn't be broken. This is one of them. If your application really, really, needs to do this, then you need a different solution than a conventional Web application.

Comment: We will just have to agree to disagree on this. There are no principles that shouldn't be broken ever. I challenge you to find a concise list of such "general principles" that you can get everyone to agree on. Web application technology has many benefits beyond public internet applications. In our company we provide a wealth of internal tools via RoR and it works just fine.

Comment: I don't agree to disagree -- I think that's sloppy. If two reasonable people come to different logical conclusions from the same data, that usually means *at least* one of them is wrong and that more learning is necessary. Under what circumstances do you think it's appropriate to do what the OP was asking? (IMHO this would be just as wrong on an internal tool as a public one, so I don't know why you dragged that in.)

Comment: And yes, there are lots of principles that should always be adhered to -- at least in particular problem domains. Examples include test-first development, use of version control, certain database design fundamentals, avoidance of inline JavaScript....

Comment: Our customers required, and it was a hard requirement that all reports open in a new window or tab. REQUIRED. Customer. Finally, you don't have to agree to disagree, but you're not going to change my mind and clearly I'm not going to change yours so I'm not going to beat my head against this particular wall. That's what agreeing to disagree means. :P

Comment: That's a different requirement from what the OP is asking for. He's asking for *preventing* his site from opening in more than one tab. PREVENTING.

Comment: @Marnen Laibow-Koser You get me wrong I am not limiting user from opening tab. I want redirect to other action if same action is called on other tab.

Comment: OK, so you want a particular action only opened on one tab at once, right? If so, still same answer.

Comment: jaydel: You *will* get me to change my mind if you provide a good argument for me to do so. Saying "I'm not going to change your mind, so I won't argue" essentially tells me that you don't have a good argument to make...and saying "You're not going to change my mind" tells me that you don't care about logical arguments anyway. :)

Comment: Still waiting for the logic...where did you provide it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no way to achieve what you want to do and rightly so. The code on you web page should relate to that page alone and I expect there would be serious security implicatoins if you were able to query what tabs and pages the client/browser had open.

On possible option would be to create a link to [launch your site in a new window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) with the options set to remove menu, toolbars etc.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the comments already made, it's not up to you to stop users from opening multiple tabs. If it causes performance problems for them, then they will stop doing it

In the past I have been guilty of disabling 'right-click' event for certain ajax-powered links, where opening the link in a new page would not render the desired content, but would instead display the same content in another tab. But it's a bad practice, and in the end came down to my inadequate use of JS.